# Can't login to admin

Tags: admin, login

When I try to login to the admin panel I get a

> 404 error

I can access the login page, and if I try to login with a wrong password, I get the

> Invalid User Name or Password

message. If I remove the `index.php` in the web address after I have tried to login I get access, but I need to do that every time I enter a new page. I have seen some solutions that includes editing the core files, but i don't want to do that...

Anyone who knows how to fix this?

Comment: I have been through this problem. Try many things but eventually reinstalling the whole magento solve the problem. Let's see if someone else got a better solution. Thank you

Comment: is by any chance the url of your instance `localhost/something_here`?

Comment: No, its a not on localhost

Comment: Did you enable / disable / change the admin option of index.php for the urls?  How about for the admin?

Comment: have a look in to the base url and secure base url, stored in your core_config_data table

Comment: Seems like you don't have mod_rewrite php extension enabled.